# Generating element of an ideal of $\Bbb Z^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of the ring $\Bbb Z^n$. We know that $I$ is finitely generated as an ideal (finite product of noetherian is noetherian), but actually it is generated by a single element, as a finite product of PIDs is a PIR.

> How do I find a generating element of $I$? Is there any algorithm? For instance how would you proceed for $I=\langle(4,0,2),(2,-2,0)\rangle$ or $J=\langle(-2,4,0,2),(2,-2,0,1)\rangle$?

Obviously, $\langle x_1,\dots,x_m\rangle=\langle x_1 \rangle+ \dots +\langle x_m \rangle$,but this is not always equal to $\langle x_1 + \cdots + x_m \rangle$ (see $m=2,x_2=-x_1$). So I'm not sure what to do.

Thank you!

Comment: $I$ is a direct product of $n$ principal ideals, and a generator of it is the $n$-tuple consisting of those generators. In your particular case $I=2\mathbb Z\times2\mathbb Z\times2\mathbb Z=\left<(2,2,2)\right>$.

Comment: Thank you! The ideal $\langle (a_{11},\dots,a_{1n}) ; \dots ; (a_{m1},\dots a_{mn}) \rangle$ is equal to $I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n$ where $I_k = \langle a_{1k}, \dots, a_{mk} \rangle$, is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments: 
The ideal $\langle (a_{11},\dots,a_{1n}) ; \dots ; (a_{m1},\dots a_{mn}) \rangle$ is equal to $I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n$ where $I_k = \langle a_{1k}, \dots, a_{mk} \rangle$.